# Get Alfresco NodeRef by path

Tags: java, lucene, alfresco

I want to get the NodeRef of a document (or space) stored in Alfresco.

My code is in Java, running within Alfresco (for instance in an AMP).

How to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is probably using the [NodeLocatorService](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/nodelocator/NodeLocatorService.html) and the [XPath locatorName](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/nodelocator/XPathNodeLocator.html) + an xpath expression

Under the hood, that uses the search service, but it wraps up a lot of the complexity for you!

To use it, get the `NodeLocatorService` injected into your bean, then do something like:

```
 Map<String,Serializable> params = new HashMap<>();
 params.put("query", "/x:path/to:node/pa:th");
 NodeRef nodeRef = nodeLocatorService.getNode("xpath",null,params);
```

Other [NodeLocators exist](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/nodelocator/NodeLocator.html) for other lookups, and it's also available remotely [via `/alfresco/service/api/nodelocator/{node_locator_name}?params`](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/RESTful-NodelocatorNode-locatorGet.html)

Comment: Shameless plug - this is one of the things covered in my [25 Alfresco things you might not know (but should!)](http://beecon.buzz/) talk at BeeCon next month!

Comment: Nice! Do I also have to ISO9075-encode path elements?

Comment: I *think* it largely maps onto the same code you wrote, just with fewer lines and less worries on error handling, so I believe you do

Comment: I just tried this, and the unfortunate result is that it creates race conditions. Recently created nodes are often not seen, sometimes even after a few seconds. This is sure to lead to errors when many users create and delete content at the same time. Maybe I should have stated this explicitly in my question? Do you prefer me to create a separate question similar to this one but asking for solutions that do not create race conditions? Thanks always! :-)

Comment: It's powered by SOLR, which is eventually consistent. That's entirely expected behaviour. You'd need to ask a new question if you care about immediately consistent APIs, of which there are a lot fewer since 4.x for performance reasons

Comment: Understood! Here is the separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225467/get-alfresco-noderef-by-path-real-time-race-condition-safe

Comment: Just to add one point as I missed out. While doing the dependency injection for the nodelocatorService in your spring xml file, be careful you make the following entry:                                                                                  <property name="nodelocatorService" ref="nodeLocatorService"/>      instead of                                                                                      <property name="nodelocatorService" ref="NodeLocatorService"/>   Otherwise, you may get the following error. NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'NodeLocatorService' is defined

Answer (score 3):

The following Java method gets the NodeRef of the Alfresco document or space you specify:

```
/**
 * Get a NodeRef by its path.
 * @path as displayed by the Node Browser.
 * @return the NodeRef, or null if no NodeRef matches this path.
 */
private NodeRef getNode(String path) {
    logger.debug("Getting NodeRef for path:\"" + path + "\"");
    ResultSet results = null;
    try {
        StoreRef storeRef = new StoreRef(StoreRef.PROTOCOL_WORKSPACE, "SpacesStore");
        results = searchService.query(storeRef, SearchService.LANGUAGE_LUCENE,
            "PATH:\"" + path + "\"");
        if (results.length() == 0) {
            logger.debug("Zero matches for path: " + path);
            return null;
        }
        NodeRef nodeRef = results.getNodeRef(0);
        logger.debug("NodeRef for \"" + path + "\" is " + nodeRef);
        return nodeRef;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        logger.debug("Exception while searching for path: " + path, e);
        if (results != null) {
            results.close();
        }
        return null; // The node does not exist
    }
    finally {
        if (results != null) {
            results.close();
        }
    }
}

private SearchService searchService; // Be sure to set this, probably via Spring.
```

Be aware that each level in `path` must:

- have a namespace
- be escaped by ISO9075 (in Java code: `ISO9075.encode(level)`)

Examples:

- /app:company_home/app:dictionary/app:space_templates/cm:MyTemplate
- /app:company_home/app:shared/cm:abc/cm:def/cm:My_x0020_Document.txt
- /app:company_home/app:shared/cm:_x0031_23

To find out what is the path of a particular document or folder, the Node Browser (in Admin Tools) is your friend:

[image: Primary path in Alfresco Node Browser, ISO9075]

*I make the method above public domain, please fix or comment if you notice anything that can be improved, thanks! :-)*

Answer (score 0):

Path queries and not the fastest, though, especially if you're on Lucene. You should think of an alternative ways to find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

## Use the GET /nodes​/{nodeId}

Just provide the root folder constant Id as I did in the image
Then provide the document relative path

[image]