# Get Alfresco NodeRef by path (real-time, race condition safe)

Tags: java, alfresco

I want to get the NodeRef of a document (or space) stored in Alfresco.

My code is in Java, running within Alfresco (for instance in an AMP).

My code needs to be safe against race conditions, for instance it must find nodes that have been created a second before. In this context, the [usual methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131644/get-alfresco-noderef-by-path) (search-based) can not be used.

How to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to avoid anything that touches SOLR, as [those APIs are only Eventually Consistent](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/solr-event-consistency.html)

Specifically, you need an API that's based on [canned queries](http://smasue.github.io/alf-canned-queries). The main ones for your use-case are [NodeService.getChildAssocs](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/AlfrescoOne/5.0/PublicAPI/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/NodeService.html#getChildAssocs(org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef)) and [NodeService.getChildByName](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/AlfrescoOne/5.0/PublicAPI/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/NodeService.html#getChildByName(org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef,%20org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName,%20java.lang.String)). Some of [FileFolderService](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/model/FileFolderService.html) will work immediately too

Your best bet would be to split a path into components, then do a recursive / looping descent through it. Depending on if you want it by Name (`cm:name`) or QName (based on the assoc), you'd use one of the two `NodeService` methods

eg (not fully tested...)

```
String[] parts = path.split("\\/");
NodeRef nodeRef = nodeService.getRootNode(StoreRef.STORE_REF_WORKSPACE_SPACESSTORE);
for (String name : parts) {
   NodeRef child = nodeService.getChildByName(nodeRef, ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS, name);
   if (child == null) 
      throw new Exception("Path part not found "+name+" in "+path+" at "+nodeRef);
   nodeRef = child;
}
return nodeRef;
```

Answer (score 3):

This method gets the company home NodeRef, which is always available (at least from an Alfresco-based application's point of view), then uses [FileFolderService.resolveNamePath](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/model/FileFolderService.html#resolveNamePath-org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef-java.util.List-) which is not search-based.

Syntax example of expected path: `/Company Home/Shared/My Folder/123.txt`

```
public NodeRef getNode(String path) {

    // Get company home NodeRef. No race condition because it is always exists.
    NodeRef companyHomeNode = nodeService.getRootNode(StoreRef.STORE_REF_WORKSPACE_SPACESSTORE);

    // Get NodeRef for the path using path elements and resolveNamePath.
    List<String> pathElements = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(path.split("/")));
    pathElements.remove(0); // Remove leading empty element before first slash
    pathElements.remove(0); // Remove Company Home element
    try {
        FileInfo fileInfo = fileFolderService.resolveNamePath(
                companyHomeNode, pathElements);
        return fileInfo.getNodeRef();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return null; // No node with such a path.
    }
}
```

*Public domain, feel free to edit and improve :-)*

Comment: `FileFolderService.resolveNamePath` calls `searchSimple()` method and this calls `nodeService.getChildByName()`. So I would recommend directly call the `nodeService.getChildByName()` rather calling `FileFolderSerivce.resolveNamePath()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! My goal was to not reinvent the wheel, and thus do one call rather than implement the loop myself. But projects that value performance over reuse should use Gagravarr's solution indeed :-)

Answer (score 0):

Transactional queries are supported, at least to some extent.
http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/intrans-metadata-overview.html

Comment: Could you please explain this will help when different users call different Web Scripts that modify the same nodes at the same time? Thank you! :-)